# How to make Windows 7 match my Japanese MacbookPro keyboard layout?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, macbook-pro, keyboard-layout

I have a Japanese MacbookPro. The keyboard looks like this :

[image: Japanese Keyboard]

I installed a Japanese Windows 7 on it, using [Bootcamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29).
Under Windows 7, the keyboard layout is not correct.
For example, when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>, the output is **`(`**, like if it where a [US keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#United_States), while I would want it to be **`)`**, like with the normal [Japanese keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Japanese).

How can I fix this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem, thanks to the hints given in [this thread on Microsoft answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/cant-properly-type-with-japanese-ime-on-the/a70c68a5-b63f-4785-bde5-b310e9cfa9ab).
I edited the registry value `LayerDriver JPN` changing it from kbd106.dll to kbd101.dll.
It works well now !